# Yosemite volume up and down doesn't make a feedback sound

Tags: keyboard, audio, sound-volume, macos, keybindings

Instead of playing a sound when volume up/down is pressed on the keyboard it now plays a sound when you hold down SHIFT + Vol Up / Vol Down.  How does one configure it to work like it did before?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is an intentional change of the preferences.

[image]

You can turn the audio feedback back on in System Preferences -> Sound and checking `Play feedback when volume is changed`

Comment: The noise is different as well. Not sure how I feel about this - like when my mood ring was stolen.

Comment: Note for geeks: try shift+opt while changing volume)

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you want to leave it as it is right now, I prefer it this way because sometimes the click sound it produces can be painful (any way, now on Yosemite it doesn't sound that loud). What I do when I want to hear the volume indicator is to press "shift + volume key" and it will play the volume indicator again just for that time.

Comment: Nice tip, worth noting that if you have the ```Play feedback when volume is changed``` setting on, you can also hold shift when adjusting the volume and it will mute the volume indicator for just that time (ie the shift is a temporary toggle for whatever the current setting is).